# Having trouble with a file in C

Tags: c, file

im using this algorithm to read a file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;

    char a;
    fp = fopen("example.pak", "r");
    do {
      a = fgetc(fp);
      printf("%c",a);
   } while (a != EOF);
    printf("\n");
}
```

and the example.pak is like this:

```
6f6d 6272 6573 2064 6520 746f 646f 7320
6c6f 7320 6172 6368 6976 6f73 2063 6f6d
7069 6c61 646f 7320 636f 6e20 6578 7465
6e73 696f 6e20 2e6f 0a23 206e 6563 6573
6172 696f 7320 7061 7261 2073 7520 7072
6f79 6563 746f 2e0a 4f42 4a45 4354 5320
3d20 0a43 464c 4147 5320 3d20 2d4f 3320
2d57 616c 6c20 0a4c 444c 4942 5320 3d20
2d6c 7074 6872 6561 640a 0a23 2050 756e
746f 2064 6520 656e 7472 6164 6120 7061
7261 206d 616b 6520 7369 2073 6520 656a
6563 7574 6120 7369 6e20 7061 7261 6d65
7472 6f73 2e0a 616c 6c3a 2024 2854 4152
4745 5429 0a0a 2320 4573 7461 2072 6567
6c61 2063 6f6d 7069 6c61 2065 6c20 7072
6f79 6563 746f 2063 6f6d 706c 6574 6f20
756e 6120 7665 7a20 7175 6520 746f 646f
7320 6c6f 7320 6172 6368 6976 6f73 206f
626a 6574 6f0a 2320 7961 2068 616e 2073
6964 6f20 636f 6d70 696c 6164 6f73 2e0a
5441 5247 4554 3a20 2428 4f42 4a45 4354
5329 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2067 6363 202d
6f20 2428 5441 5247 4554 2920 2428 4f42
4a45 4354 5329 2024 2843 464c 4147 5329
2024 284c 444c 4942 5329 0a0a 2320 436f
```

and when i run the algorithm prints this message

```
ombres de todos los archivos compilados con extension .o
# necesarios para su proyecto.
OBJECTS = 
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall 
LDLIBS = -lpthread

# Punto de entrada para make si se ejecuta sin parametros.
all: $(TARGET)

# Esta regla compila el proyecto completo una vez que todos los archivos objeto
# ya han sido compilados.
TARGET: $(OBJECTS)
        gcc -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

# Co�
```

but when i try to save it in another file, the other file  has the hexadecimals values of the input... how i can solve this?

i want to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;

    char a;
    fp = fopen("example.pak", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("test4.txt", "w");
    do {
      a = fgetc(fp);
      fputc(a, fp2);
   } while (a != EOF);

}
```

and in the "test4.txt" says everything that i show before like

```
ombres de todos los archivos compilados con extension .o
    # necesarios para su proyecto.
    OBJECTS = 
    CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall 
    LDLIBS = -lpthread bla bla ba...
```

@immibis i've to work with hexdump files, well they are not exactly hexdump's

Comment: How did you get the hex dump?

Comment: Aside: you probably shouldn't print `EOF`.

Comment: Check the result of `fopen` and `a` should be an `int`. Also you could use a loop like `while((a = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {...}`.

Comment: Your question lacks the important details like how are you writing to the other file, and as @Hurkyl said you should not print `EOF` it's not a character that you put in a file, it's a special value used by the library functions to mark en end of a file. And as @pzaenger said, `EOF` requires that `a` is an `int`.

Comment: The input file is hex ASCII?